# Does isomorphism of sets of natural transformations imply isomorphism between functors?

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

I am studying Proposition 3.7.4 of Francis Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Algebra*.
For specific functors $F,G:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$, he shows that for any functor $H:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$, we always have the bijection
$$\textbf{Nat}(F,H)\cong\textbf{Nat}(G,H)$$
He then claims that by taking $H = F$ for which we find $\textbf{Nat}(F,F)\cong\textbf{Nat}(G,F)$ and then $H = G$ for which we find $\textbf{Nat}(F,G)\cong\textbf{Nat}(G,G)$, it follows that $F\cong G$.

I do not see why this is true? Is this a general fact, or does Borceux silently depend on the chosen bijection between the sets of natural transformations?

Comment: Is the bijection natural in $H$? If so this is just the Yoneda lemma.

Comment: Yes, after thinking some more about it, this is probably the case. Borceux does not really write down which bijection he takes, but I think it is possible to construct one which is natural.

Comment: It's understood that all the bijections involved are those induced by the universal properties at play, so it is indeed natural.